# How to get new points of line after transformation in KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, konvajs

Let's say I draw a rectangle on Canvas using Konva.Line (I don't want to use Konva.Rect for application specific reasons) by giving it following points array

`let points = [300, 100, 500, 100, 500, 200, 300, 200, 300, 100]`

Next I do some transformations on it. I scale X by 1.5 and Y by 2.5. I also rotate it by 45 degrees counterclockwise.

Now I want to know the new coordinates of the points using the Konva.Line object. I know it has position(), rotation(), scaleX(), scaleY() and the original points array. But how do I use these to arrive at the final coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get absolute position of any point of a line you can use this:

```js
line.getAbsoluteTransform().point({ x: 300, y: 100})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-transform-position-forked-ed8xj7

Main logic

```
onTransformEnd={(e) => {
                const node = shapeRef.current;
                console.log(node.points());
                let points = [];
                let flatendPoints = deflat(2, node.points());
                flatendPoints.forEach((k, i) => {
                  let { x, y } = node
                    .getAbsoluteTransform()
                    .point({ x: k[0], y: k[1] });
                  points.push([x, y]);
                });

                console.log(points.flat(2));
                setCircles(points);
              }}
```

If u are updating values on redux/state. be aware to clear scaled values.

```
node.scaleX(1)
node.scaleY(1)
node.position({ x: 0, y: 0 })
```